# SUMIFS Formula With Empty Criteria in Cell Reference

Tags: excel, excel-formula, sumifs

My `SUMIFS` formula gets its criteria from a drop down filter. Need to be able sum all values IF the filter is left blank.

[image: Vendor is the Filter - Cell = $B$2]

```
=SUMIFS(Data!AX:AX,Data!J:J,B2)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use an [`IF` function](https://support.office.com/article/if-function-69aed7c9-4e8a-4755-a9bc-aa8bbff73be2) to determine whether the criteria cell is blank, and if it is, use a "regular" [`SUM` function](https://supphttps://support.office.com/article/sum-function-043e1c7d-7726-4e80-8f32-07b23e057f89nId=953ccfff-609f-44f4-8cc0-b70c6af5f143&ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US).

Something like,

```
=IF(B2="",SUM(Data!AX:AX),SUMIFS(Data!AX:AX,Data!J:J,B2))
```

Comment: Worked - Thanks!

Comment: you're welcome (I just corrected the links, they were for VBA before)